# Meaning of "put it down"

Tags: phrases, slang

What does "put it down" mean in Brandy's song? I tried googling it, but all I got was the song's lyrics.

Comment: Not everyone knows what a "Brandy" is. May you post a true  link to the song lyrics?

Comment: Lyrics interpretation requests are out of scope for this site. They are a form of literary interpretation or criticism, and that is a very subjective area with no clear right or wrong answers.

Comment: FWIW, the Urban Dictionary has an entry for "put it down".  It's slang for: "Doing what needs to be done, at any given moment. To do the right thing at the right time..."  **Example**, "Are you going to try out for American Idol?"  "Yeah, I'm gonna ***put it down*** at that audition!"

Answer (score 1):

My take on the phrase is as it is defined by the [Urban Dictionary](http://www.urbandictionary.com/define.php?term=put%20it%20down). It's more of a challenge, where Brandy thinks it isn't possible to fall in love, and Breezy is asserting that she will.

Answer (score 0):

Listening to [Brandy's song](http://www.azlyrics.com/lyrics/brandy/putitdown.html), I could interpret it as "put it down to experience", it seems to be a short version of the idiom, meaning:

> "to decide that instead of being upset about something bad that has
>   happened or that you have done, you will learn from it."

Okay, so you made a mistake - you just have to **put it down to experience** and carry on with your life.
There's nothing we can do about it now, we'll just have to experience.

------//--------

However, researching for "put it down" we get to the conclusion it is an urban slang with similar meaning to that of "put it down to experience". [See reference here >](http://www.urbandictionary.com/define.php?term=put+it+down)

**1. put it down**

In the process of "doing it"

Im gonna put it down fo real

**2. put it down**

Doing what needs to be done, at any given moment.To do the right thing at the right time... Can also be used before going out and having a good time.
1.We gone hit the club tonight, you tryina roll?

-Yeah man ima Put it down tonight, trust.

2.Hey man I heard your girl was with some other foo...

-I know man ima put it down right now.

Comment: Sorry, Monecchi, I don't think it means "put it down to experience" at all.  How are you extrapolating that from the Urban Dictionary definition?  It means "I'm going to do something", as in, "I'm putting it down, man!"